# Is there a way to retrieve all editable cells from kendo grid?

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid in which fields are editable based on some condition like:

```
 //var isEditable= some condition

 fields: {
             Id: { type: "int", editable: false },
             Amount: {type: "number", editable: isEditable},
         }
```

I want to get all editable cells and perforn something on them before they are displayed.

Currently i'm using dataBound event iterate rows and cells and find desired cells

```
dataBound: function(e){
            var rows = e.sender.tbody.children();
            for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
            var row = $(rows[j]);
            if (isEditable){
                   var cell1 = row.children().eq("hardcoded index");
                   var cell2 = row.children().eq("hardcoded index 2");
                   var cell3 = row.children().eq("hardcoded index 3");
                   ......
                   ......
                   // perform action
            }
 }
```

Is there a better approach to achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried setting a class on those elements that are editable?

Comment: Yes i can set a class to the columns that may or may not be editable (depending on the condition). I was currious if there is an approach of using kendo framework. There are a couple of way of achieving that using CSS and javascript.

Comment: I've also noticed that after first edit the td element gets data-role="editable" attribute so i was thinking that there is a way of getting the editable fields in other way without having to decorate them with css classes, etc.

Comment: If you use a template for the fields, you can set it directly on the TD element.

Comment: Since you indicate that you want to do something to them before they display - you could possibly address that in a template, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to do something to the editable element before display, I would use a template to accomplish that.  Here is an example that turns the background color red if the Amount field is editable:

```
<script id="editableTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  #if (Editable)  { #
    <div style='background-color:red'>#=Amount#</div> 
  # } else { #
    <div>#=Amount#</div> 
  # } #
<script>
```

Another way to approach this is to take parameters by wrapping the template in a function:

```
function foo(isEdit, value) {
    if(isEdit){
        return "<div style='background-color:red'>" + value + "</div>";
    } else {
        return "<div>" + value + "</div>";
    }
}
```

You can then set the column template as:

```
{
    field: "Amount",
    type: "number",
    template: function(data) {
        return kendo.template("#=foo(isEditable, Amount)#")
    },
    editable: isEditable
}
```

[Here is a basic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/yfqvM/55/).